# Optimizing mongo $match

Tags: mongodb, optimization, mongodb-query

I am trying to optimize an aggregate query using Mongo indexes. I have an aggregate query:

```
  aggregate: [{
    $match: {
       questionId: '123',
       optionId: '234',
       $or: [ /* dynamically created */ ]
    }
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }]
```

My index is `createIndex({ questionId: 1, optionId: 1 })`.

Should this help with my query times? Is there any other way to go about optizing a query like this?

Comment: Why not to try and check what `explain` says?